# Disable ability to list objects in OVH OpenStack Object Storage

Tags: openstack, openstack-swift, object-storage, ovh, openstack-horizon

I created an OVH Public Cloud Object Storage Public Container and I can't disable the ability for everyone to list objects in this container. OVH uses OpenStack Object Storage.

It is really annoying, because I want to expose publicly each object stored in this container by my website, but I don't want that everyone can access the full list of objects stored in my container.
Do you have any idea on how to solve this? I can't find this in OVH or OpenStack documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No solution yet?

Comment: @EzequielAdrian I don't know.
I switched to Scaleway Object Storage(AWS behind) and you can manage it from the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

OVH documentation:

> By configuring a container in static mode, OVHcloud's Object Storage
>   will act as a standard web server by first serving "index.html", or
>   presenting an HTML index of the objects' URLs if no "index.html"
>   objects exist by default.

Insert an empty index.html file into each folder in a container to disable file listings.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set ACL meta data in the container ? [container-acls](https://docs.openstack.org/swift/latest/overview_acl.html#container-acls)

Comment: Yes I tried this. It worked at the start but it seems OVH resets automatically ACL when I come back in the admin dashboard of my container. So each time I come back on the OVH dashboard I have to reset ACL to disable listings. It seems very immature solution.